# Integration of trig function

Tags: calculus

What is $$\int (\cos x- \sin x )  \cos^{10}(2x) \  dx$$
My attempt is to turn $\cos 2x$ into $\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ then into $(\cos x-\sin x)*(\cos x+\sin x)$. It becomes $(\cos x-\sin x)^{11}(\cos x+\sin x)$ From here I am stuck in substitution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it becomes $(\cos x-\sin x)^{11}(\cos x+\sin x)^{10}$.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem. You almost did it. So we have

\begin{align}
I&=\int(\cos x-\sin x)\cos^{10}2x\,dx=\int(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^{10}dx\\
&=\int(\cos x-\sin x)^{11}(\cos x+\sin x)^{10}dx.
\end{align}

Now notice

\begin{align}
\cos x+\sin x&=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}),\\
\cos x-\sin x&=\sqrt{2}\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4}).
\end{align}

Therefore, we have

\begin{align}
I&=2^{21/2}\int\cos^{11}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\sin^{10}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})dx\\
&=1024\sqrt{2}\int\cos^{10}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\sin^{10}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\,d\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\\
&=1024\sqrt{2}\int\left[1-\sin^{2}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\right]^5\sin^{10}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\,d\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}),
\end{align}
which becomes integration of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int (\cos x- \sin x )  \cos^{10}(2x) \  dx\\
&=&\int\cos x  \cos^{10}(2x) \  dx-\int \sin x  \cos^{10}(2x) \  dx\\
&=&\int(1-2\sin^2x)^{10} \  d\sin x+\int(2\cos^2x-1)^{10}\  d\cos x\\
&=&\int(1-2u^2)^{10}du+\int(1-2v^2)^{10}dv\\
&=&\int\sum_{k=0}^{10}(-1)^k\binom{10}{k}2^ku^{2k}du+\int\sum_{k=0}^{10}(-1)^k\binom{10}{k}2^kv^{2k}dv\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{10}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{10}{k}2^k(u^{2k+1}+v^{2k+1})+C\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{10}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{10}{k}2^k(\sin^{2k+1}x+\cos^{2k+1}x)+C
\end{eqnarray}
where $u=\sin x,v=\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $$(\cos x+\sin x)^2+(\cos x-\sin x)^2=2\iff(\cos x+\sin x)^2=?$$

Now for $$\int(\cos x+\sin x)^m(\cos x-\sin x)^{2n+1}dx$$

set $\cos x+\sin x=u\implies(\cos x-\sin x)dx=du$

and $(\cos x-\sin x)^2=2-u^2$

Comment: Apparently this doesn't make the problem easier!

Comment: @MyGlasses, So, it reduces to $$\int u^m(2-u^2)^n du$$ right?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, use the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$. This yields $$\frac1{2^{11}}\int(z+z^{-1}+iz-iz^{-1})(z^2+z^{-2})^{10}\frac{dz}{iz},$$ a rational expression in $z$, which you can integrate term by term.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was amazing, so next you can do this.

$$(\cos x − \sin x)^{11}*(\cos x + \sin x)$$

Consider $\cos x-\sin x = u$, therefore, $(-\sin x - \cos x) \, dx = du$,
substitute $dx$ and $u$ in the your integral.

So, $\int (\cos x − \sin x)^{11} \, (\cos x + \sin x) \, dx$

will become

$$\int u^{11}  (- du) = - \int u^{11}  du = - \frac{u^{12}}{12} + C_{0}$$

Substitute $u$, which gives
$$- \frac{(\cos x - \sin x)^{12}}{12} + C_{0}$$